# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode' when sending an email

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I want to have this code where I can have a csv file with a row of names next to a row of emails and then email every email on the list but have every name in the message.
Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import csv


def nobrackets(current):
    return str(current).replace('[','').replace(']','')
def noastrick(current):
    return str(current).replace('\'','').replace('\'','')

email = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxxxx'
send_to_email = []
subject = 'Whats up doc' # The subject line
message = ()
names = []
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['Subject'] = 'Whats up doc'

 # Attach the message to the MIMEMultipart object


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
with open('Emails.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        names.append(line[0])
        names_var = names
        send_to_email.append(line[1])
        send_to_email_var = send_to_email
        
        message = (f"Hey {noastrick(nobrackets(names_var))} how has your day been?")
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
        msg['From'] = 'xxxxxxxxx'

        msg['To'] = send_to_email_var

        server.login(email, password)
        text = msg.as_string() # You now need to convert the MIMEMultipart object to a string to send
        server.sendmail(email, send_to_email_var, text)
        names.clear()
        message = ()
        send_to_email = []
server.quit()
```

The error I get is File/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/email/**_policybase.py**", line 369, in _fold
parts.append(h.encode(linesep=self.linesep, maxlinelen=maxlinelen))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

The reason I change the lists into variables is because I thought that might fix the error I got. I am somewhat new to python, and I realized the error is in a file called _policybase.py and it might be like built into the python application I installed on my computer, but I don't know how to edit that file, or fix that error.

Comment: The `nobrackets` and `noastrick` functions look suspiciously like you don't understand the difference between the *contents* of a string and its `repr()` which Python's REPL uses to show an unambiguous human-readable version of a value. If you see `['hello', 'world']` that represents a list of the strings `hello` and `world`. The strings themselves don't actually contain any single quotes (not asterisks, by the way, and certainly not "astricks") or square brackets; those are purely presentation aids.

Comment: And needless to say, there are **absolutely no situations** where editing the files in Python's standard library makes any sense whatsoever for a beginner.

Answer (score 10):

This answer by @snakecharmerb is mostly correct:

> The problem is that the code is setting msg['to'] to a list instead of a string. smtplib.server.sendmail will accept a list of strings as its toaddrs argument, but an email message does not (if multiple to addresses are required, call msg['to'] = address once for each address).

However, you don't need to send the mail to each recipient individually via a for-loop. Instead just assign the list as comma-separated string to msg["To"] like this:

```
msg["To"] = ", ".join(send_to_email_var)
```

Comment: @randomperson it would be great if you could mark the answer which helped you as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the code is setting `msg['to']` to a list instead of a string.  `smtplib.server.sendmail` will accept a list of strings as its `toaddrs` argument, but an email message does not (if multiple to addresses are required, call `msg['to'] = address` once for each address).

Also, it isn't necessary to stringify the message to send it: instead, use [smtplib.server.send_message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message)

This code ought to work:

```py
with open('Emails.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        names_var = line[0]
        send_to_email_var = line[1]

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = 'Whats up doc'
        message = (f"Hey {noastrick(nobrackets(names_var))} how has your day been?")
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
        msg['From'] = 'xxxxxxxxx'

        msg['To'] = send_to_email_var

        server.login(email, password)
        server.send_message(msg, email, send_to_email_var)
server.quit()
```

Comment: That fixed the error so thanks, man. The only problem is that it is sending to multiple people at the same time. I had a csv with three names and emails that I was testing it with, and  it was sent to all 3 emails(as a group email), and the message inside was the message 3 times with the 3 different names.

Comment: I've amended the answer to show the message object being initialised inside the for loop, so we get a new message object for each iteration.