# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'. How do i send Email via Excel? Python

Tags: python, email

So I'm trying to send an e-mail from Excel with Python. Right now  I just have all the e-mails set up in column A1 separated by semicolons. If I put the e-mails into Python directly, they send out but when I use the Python call-out, it freaks out giving me this error. How exactly can I make this work?

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

server = smtplib.SMTP('relay.xxx.com')
email_df = pandas.read_excel(f"E-mails.xlsx", sheet_name="Emails", nrows=1, usecols = "A")
sender = 'email@email.com'

receivers = 'Email'
receivers = list(email_df)

print(receivers)
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')

msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
msg['From'] = sender

with smtplib.SMTP('relay.xxx.com') as server:
    msg['To'] = receivers
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, bytes(msg.as_string()))
    print(f"Successfully sent email to: {receivers}")
```

I don't want multiple e-mails to be sent out. I want 1 single e-mail with a bunch of e-mails in the address box.

Alternatively, if there's a way can read it by column, (addr1 in a1, addr in a2) that'd also be better.

Appreciate it.

Comment: Your "receivers" variable should be a string and not a list. You may find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044254/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-encode-when-sending-an-email

Comment: I mean, I believe I saw this upon my research but I'm not exactly sure what they're doing to make it a string. Every adjustment I try to make seems to only give me a new error that I'm not sure if I'm making it worse.

Comment: What does your print(receivers) output? A list of the email addresses as expected?

Comment: When I print, i get "0 e-mail@email.com; e-mail2@email.com...

Comment: Is there a specific need for you to use Excel and Pandas as opposed to a CSV or just plain text file?

Comment: At this point, I'll take what I can get. We're using Excel because it's what were already using. It's where the e-mails already are.

Are you saying if I did .csv, this would be easier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250241/discussion-between-dexsana-and-bigkeefer).

Comment: Simplifies a little, yes. You mention in your post that each email address in a1, a2, etc. would be better for you. Is that how you have it at the moment in your spreadsheet and do you have a column heading like "email/address" in that spreadsheet?

Comment: Right now it's all packaged into a1.

And the column is labeled as "Email"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your email addresses (from your df) into a list in the desired format, e.g.:

```
print(receivers)    
['email1@email1.com', 'email2@email2.com', 'email3@email3.com']
```

then you can add this after its assignment to turn it into a string for send_mail (as it requires a string instead of a list):

```
receivers = ", ".join(receivers)
```

You mention that it would be ideal if you had an email address per row under column A in your spreadsheet. So if you can get your Excel spreadsheet into this format (with a column heading of "Email") then you can do this to get the aforementioned list:

```
email_df = pandas.read_excel(f"E-mails.xlsx", sheet_name="Emails", usecols = "A")
receivers = email_df['Email'].tolist()
```

So, for completeness (with Excel spreadsheet in its new format of one email address per row under column A), your code would change to:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

server = smtplib.SMTP('relay.xxx.com')

email_df = pandas.read_excel(f"E-mails.xlsx", sheet_name="Emails")
receivers = email_df['Email'].tolist()

print(receivers)  # Check list is one valid email address per element

receivers = ", ".join(receivers)

sender = 'email@email.com'
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')

msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
msg['From'] = sender

with smtplib.SMTP('relay.xxx.com') as server:
    msg['To'] = receivers
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, bytes(msg.as_string(), encoding='utf-8'))
    print(f"Successfully sent email to: {receivers}")
```

Comment: When I add "receivers = email_df['Email'---

I get:

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I have added whole code change in answer to see if it helps

Comment: Now Im getting: 'string argument without an encoding'

Comment: That's coming from bytes() in your sendmail line: I have amended full code in my answer to see if that helps you.

Comment: Now it's 'object of type 'method' has no len() ' on the same line.... It never ends!

Comment: Oh wait nevermind. I didnt see the encoding update. Now were fixed. Thank you so much. Lol

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you are up and running :)

Answer (score 1):

If you build a message, you'd better use the `send_message` interface. And I would suggest to use the newer `EmailMessage` interface which is cleaner and simpler that the older `MimeMultipart` one:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

...
msg = EmailMessage()

msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
msg['From'] = sender

msg.set_payload('Message text.\nLine 2...')
# or eventually add parts with msg.add_related(...), msg.add_alternative(..)
#  or msg.add_attachment(...)


with smtplib.SMTP('relay.xxx.com') as server:
    msg['To'] = receivers
    server.send_messages(msg)
    print(f"Successfully sent email to: {receivers}")
```